# Symfony - Update a unique OneToMany relation property

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

A Company can have multiple emails and all emails have to be unique.
This my Entites for Company and CompanyEmail

**CompanyEmail Entity:**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CompanyEmailRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity("name")
 */
class CompanyEmail
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=128, unique=true)
     * @Assert\Email()
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Company", inversedBy="emails")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $company;

    // ...
}
```

**Company Entity:**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CompanyRepository")
 */
class Company
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\CompanyEmail", mappedBy="company", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist"})
     * @Assert\Valid
     */
    private $emails;

    // ...
}
```

and I'm using an custom *EmailsInputType* that use this **DataTransformer**

```
class EmailArrayToStringTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    public function transform($emails): string
    {
        return implode(', ', $emails);
    }


    public function reverseTransform($string): array
    {
        if ($string === '' || $string === null) {
            return [];
        }

        $inputEmails = array_filter(array_unique(array_map('trim', explode(',', $string))));

        $cEmails = [];
        foreach($inputEmails as $email){
            $cEmail = new CompanyEmail();
            $cEmail->setName($email);
            $cEmails[] = $cEmail;
        }

        return $cEmails;
    }
}
```

and in the Controller a use this edit method

```
/**
     * @Route("/edit/{id}", name="admin_company_edit", requirements={"id": "\d+"}, methods={"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function edit(Request $request, $id): Response
    {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $company = $entityManager->getRepository(Company::class)->find($id);

        $form = $this->createForm(CompanyType::class, $company);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $entityManager->flush();
        }
    }
```

There is two problems with this code

1 - In the edit form when i try to keep an already saved email Symfony generate a validation error that tells that this email is already exits.

2 - When I remove the validation restriction from the code, Symfony thrown the database error "*Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry ... *"

What i should do to make my code work as expected !

Comment: This question is not clear at all: what do you need and what's the issue? ie.: is the error (whatever it is) shown when you update the entity *without* adding any email (just trying to guess what's the issue here). Please, provide an accurate description of the use case and an accurate description of the scenario where existing code fails. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I do my best to illustrate my problem, but my English is so bad, I will try again

Comment: DonCallisto Suppose that we have a Company entity that already have two emails, when i will try to updated the entity without changing emails (keeping the same old emails), a validation error of @UnqiueEntity constraints will be showing, this is the problem it's like Symfony don't know that I'm trying to updating not to inserting !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is right here

```
public function reverseTransform($string): array
{
  [...]

  foreach($inputEmails as $email){
    $cEmail = new CompanyEmail();
    [...]
  }

  [...]
}
```

You need to retrieve the `email` instead of creating new one.
So basically, inject a `CompanyEmailRepository`, try to find if email already exists (`findOneBy(['name'])`), if it does not exists, create a new one but if exists, use what you've retrieved.

Just few notes

- Pay attention to email owner (so the retrieve should be do per user I guess as no one can share the same mail UNLESS you can specify some aliases or shared address)
- Maybe you don't need an extra entity like `CompanyEmail` as you can use a `json` field where you can store them in a comma separated fashion (unless you need some extra parameters or unless you need to perform some indexing/querying operation on the emails)